# Laptop resolution gets slightly altered when extending desktop upwards

Tags: windows-7, laptop, resolution, extended-desktop

I have a laptop with a resolution of 1336x786 and running Windows 7 64bit. Recently I extended my desktop with a 22" monitor (1680x1050) through HDMI-DVI. The extra monitor is physically placed above my laptop, so I put display 2 horizontally centered on top of display 1 in the Windows display control in order to match the physical setup.

[image: Screenshot of: Control Panel > Display > Screen Resolution]

When I apply these settings, the icons on the right of my laptop desktop get shifted somewhat to the left and there is not enough space left on the right side to put them back. The icons at the bottom only have room for one line of text instead of the normal two. So it seems the resolution of my laptop gets altered somehow, although the settings still say 1336x768. This doesn't happen if I put display 2 anywhere else (to the left or bottom for example) than on top of display 1.

Does anyone know what's the cause of this and is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

A) click and drag the layout of monitor 2 a bit to the right until the left edge of monitor 2 is aligned with monitor 1, with the right edge of monitor 2 extending further past the edge of monitor 1. B) Find and use some software that gives you finer control over the arrangement of desktop icons (I personally love stardock Fences).

Explanation: my guess is that it's doing what you get at by mentioning the laptop resolution seems to be altered somehow. Maybe the resolution of monitor 1 is virtually extended to be as "wide" as monitor 2; so that Windows thinks the left edge of the desktop of monitor 1 extends to align with the left edge of the desktop of monitor 2.

With proposed solution A), I expect that then the icons of monitor 1 won't go "off" the screen to align to monitor 2, because there's not any virtual space further left to align to.

It's unfortunate if there's no built-in solution to Windows for this specific problem, or in other words that the only fix is to make sure the left edges of the desktops of vertically stacked monitors are aligned.

Comment: Unfortunately option A doesn't help. The horizontal position of display 2 doesn't seem to make any difference. I'll have to check option B later, although I am not fond of using extra software for something that should work out of the box.
It is not breaking issue, just more of an annoyance I hope to fix. Thanks for the suggestions anyway.